# How to set the startup project in Expression Blend 2

Tags: expression-blend

Does any one know how to set the startup project in Expression Blend 2?  I have a solution which builds 2 executable files.  I've set the Startup Project to the one I want to debug in Visual Studio and when I run it from VS that project launches no problem.  However if I open the solution in Blend and press F5 to run it the other project always launches.

There doesn't seem to be a way of setting the Startup project in Blend, and it does seem to respect the setting in Visual Studio.  Or am I missing something?

Why does Blend always launch the other project and is there anyway I can change this?

Thanks

Kaneda

Answer (score 0):

In the project explorer (Blend), right-click the project name within the solution and make sure 'Startup Project' is checked.

I've only got Blend 3 RC to check on at the moment but I'm pretty sure this was also in Blend 2.

Comment: Yes, that would be the logical thing to do, but alas that option is not there in Blend 2.  Could it be that Blend 2 doesn't allow you to set it?  But even then what is making it always choose the other project?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see.  Turns out that the feature was added with SP1 and I didn't have that installed.  Installed that, now my solution launches properly